# Pivotal CRM 5.7 SmartPortal size

Tags: pivotal-crm

Do anyone of You guys know if it is possible to change default size of SmartPortal based on url (webpage) size? Default it is 1/3 of screen width and 250px height.
Is it possible to change it to take whole screen width and other height?

Mayby I must create a SmartPortal plugin for that or manipulate webpage DOM?

Any advice will be helpfull :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out (thanks to ShankarSangoli).
I used jQuery to modify iframe height.
Whole dashboard is just a html table, so using some selectors I was able to change iframe height.

This is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //SmartPortal name
            var SPname = 'Name of SmartPortal';
            //function usage
            resizeSP(SPname, 400);
        });

        function resizeSP(SP, size) {
            $("table.TitleText td.TitleText:contains(" + SP + ")", parent.document).closest('#title-bar').parent().next().find('#contentNode').children(":first").css("height", size);
        }
    </script>
```

But there are some limitations!!! The html page used by SmartPortal must be in the same domain as Pivotal (JavaScript security limitations) so I saved my document on local drive and used relative URL in SP properties.

If You want to use webpage outside domain just create a html document containing iframe with target URL and load it into Pivotal.
Like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //SmartPortal name
            var SPname = 'SP name;
            //usage
            resizeSP(SPname, 400);
        });

        function resizeSP(SP, size) {
            $("table.TitleText td.TitleText:contains(" + SP + ")", parent.document).closest('#title-bar').parent().next().find('#contentNode').children(":first").css("height", size);
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: auto;
            height: 100%;
        }
        iframe {
            display:block;
            width:100%;
            border:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://www.yoursite.com"></iframe>
</body>
```

I hope that it will be helpful for anyone :)